# Handler freezes UI when processing while loop inside a runnable task [android]

Tags: java, android, handler

I want to repeat  -  -  -... so on. 
The recording (for seconds) stops when its energy reaches at some threshold value and playbacked. After playback, new recording begins. So I have to monitor the energy using buffers and begin new recording after playback time computation. My pseudocode (most simplified form) looks like this :

...

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private Handler myHandler = new Handler();

....

    private Runnable timedTask = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
           audiorecorder = new AudioRecord(...  initializes
           audiorecorder.startRecording();
           isRecording = true; 
           ElapsedTime = 0.0;
           while(true) {
                ReadByte = audiorecorder.read(buffer, 0, buffersize);
                // Write ReadByte onto file (temp.pcm)

                EnergyBuffer = <some averaged energy over a period (1 sec or so)>
                if(EnergyBuffer > Threshold)
                     break;
                ElapsedTime = ...
           }
           // audiorecorder.release, stop, and null
           // play temp.pcm using AudioTrack           

           myHandler.postDelayed(timedTask, Elapsedtime);
    };
}
```

and this is triggered by a start and a stop button as follows,

```
    StartButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myHandler.post(timedTask);
        }
    });

    StopButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myHandler.removeCallbacks(timedTask);
        }
    });
```

The problem is when audio is recording or playback, no button is working, I have to wait until it finishes the recording. How can I prevent freezing from recording? Is it just because of whileloop? Please help..!

If I run as follows, there is no error.

```
Thread t = new Thread(timedTask);
t.start();
```

This is only one-time ok, but after then when handler does in delayed time, it also freezes the UI.

Comment: please show how you define myHandler

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A handler posts runnable tasks into a looper in a thread. It doesn't on it self create a new thread on which to run the runnables on asynchronously.

When you create a handler by calling the constructor `new Handler()`, the handler will get the looper of the current thread from which the constructor was called on by default. Since you called `new Handler()` on the UI thread, any runnable given to the handler's post command will just be added to the UI thread.

You need to create a new thread and get it's looper, by doing

```
HandlerThread readThread = new HandlerThread("");
readThread.start();
myHandler = new Handler(readThread.getLooper());
```

HandlerThread is a thread that automatically sets up a looper for you to use.

Of course, you will also need to quit the thread once you don't need it

```
readThread.quit();
```

Comment: I wanted to vote up but I can't because of my low reputation. I will come back and vote near future! thanks!

Comment: @benHeo i will do that for you

Answer (score 1):

You are the genius, works like a charm and it is exactly what I worked for days, thank you so much!!
Here is the answer from my problem :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private Handler myHandler;

....

    private Runnable timedTask = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
           audiorecorder = new AudioRecord(...  initializes
           audiorecorder.startRecording();
           isRecording = true; 
           ElapsedTime = 0.0;
           while(true) {
                ReadByte = audiorecorder.read(buffer, 0, buffersize);
                // Write ReadByte onto file (temp.pcm)

                EnergyBuffer = <some averaged energy over a period (1 sec or     so)>
                if(EnergyBuffer > Threshold)
                     break;
                ElapsedTime = ...
           }
           // audiorecorder.release, stop, and null
           // play temp.pcm using AudioTrack           

           myHandler.postDelayed(timedTask, Elapsedtime);
    };
....
    protected void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        HandlerThread readThread = new HandlerThread("");
        readThread.start();
        myHandler = new Handler(readThread.getLooper());
        ...
    }
}
```